# Text not aligned

Tags: html, css, text, alignment

I created the following [HTML CSS Code](http://jsfiddle.net/85AKq/7/):

```
<div class="Pager">
  <span class="Resume">Posts 1 to 40 of 220X</span>
  <ul class="Buttons">
    <li><span>123</span></li>
  </ul>
  <div class="Clear"></div>
</div>

.Class {clear: both;}

div.Pager {}

div.Pager span.Resume {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 1;
  float: left;
}

div.Pager ul.Buttons {
  float: left;    
}

div.Pager ul.Buttons li {
  float: left;   
}

div.Pager ul.Buttons li span {
  font-family: Arial;
  font-size: 0.9em;
  line-height: 1;
}
```

Does anyone knows why the "123" text appears lower then the previous text?

Thank You,
Miguel

Comment: Take off jQuery's Normalization (checkbox to left) and it'll be more evident.

Comment: *Inspect Element* using Chrome Console or Firebug.

Comment: @BradChristie - I updated the fiddle in the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Move your "font style setting CSS" to the outermost element (`div.Pager`), and have it only on that element so you're not needlessly redefining the same thing:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/85AKq/9/

This works because `font-family`, `font-size`, `line-height` are all inheritable - the descendants can inherit those properties from the parent element.

---

I'm pretty sure this is irrelevant, but to make it work when "Normalized CSS" is turned off in jsFiddle, add `margin: 0; padding: 0; list-style: none` to your `ul`:

http://jsfiddle.net/thirtydot/85AKq/10/

Answer (score 1):

Changing the `line-height` to normal on both the spans worked for me

```
div.Pager span.Resume {
    float: left;
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: normal;
}

div.Pager ul.Buttons li span {
    font-family: Arial;
    font-size: 0.9em;
    line-height: normal;
}
```

As well as changing the `li` and `ul` to remove the dot and the spacing fixed it completely.

```
div.Pager ul.Buttons li {
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}

div.Pager ul.Buttons {
    float: left;
    list-style:none;
    padding:0;
    margin:0;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

It's because the text is inside an unordered list. Lists have automatic margin properties that are determined by the browser. In order to get it to go up to the same level you're going to have to offset it's position to the top by giving the list a `margin-top: -3px` style like so:

http://jsfiddle.net/hnYUR/

Comment: Why is this?  I'm inspecting the element and I can see that it has padding (or so it seems).  Even with padding and margin set to 0, it definitely is still a bit offset.